# return true or false existence of postgres tuple

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to implement a code written in mysql to postgres to return true or false existence of tuple, however, I have not been able to do so successfully.

The present code is the one that works without problem in mysql, however, I would like to run it in postgress. How could I implement equivalence

```
 
CREATE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13)) 
RETURNS bool
BEGIN
 
   RETURN (CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1   
        FROM client   
        WHERE phone=inPhone)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END );

 END//
```

I have tried to do this in postgres, but it doesn't work, throwing sitaxix error

```
CREATE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13))  
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM client WHERE  phone=inPhone) 
    THEN '1' 
    ELSE '0';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You're missing the `RETURNS <type>` that you had in your mysql function.

Comment: Btw you don't need the `CASE` expression - you can directly return the boolean `EXISTS(…)` value

Answer (score 1):

For a simple function like this, you don't need plpgsql. SQL is good enough, faster and can be optimized by the planner.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13))
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
    SELECT count(*) >= 1 -- will always return TRUE or FALSE
    FROM client
    WHERE phone = $1;
$$;
```

Or as @Bergi asked, using EXISTS:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchuser(inphone VARCHAR(13))
    RETURNS BOOL
    LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM client WHERE phone = $1);
$$;
```

And again using the language SQL

Comment: Why use `count(*) >= 1` instead of `EXISTS(…)`?

Comment: @Bergi: both work, I just started this pattern a decade ago... Will show the EXISTS as well

Comment: Sure it works, but I would worry that the former is not optimised and will fetch & count all rows, not just the first.

Comment: @Bergi See the update. We used this pattern for unique values, like "phone" in this example, that would find only one indexed record.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Though while it may make sense to have a unique constraint & index on `phone`, the OP didn't state anything about this

Comment: The `1` in `SELECT 1` isn't necessary [since 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/release-9-4.html): *Allow SELECT to have an empty target list*

Answer (score 0):

You can also Return `BOOLEAN` with Postgres:

```
CREATE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13)) RETURNS BOOLEAN  
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM client WHERE  phone=inPhone) 
    THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
  END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result:

```
             Table "public.client"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 phone  | text |           |          | 

postgres=# select * from client;
 phone 
-------
 foo
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from searchUser('foo');
 searchuser 
------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from searchUser('bar');
 searchuser 
------------
 f
(1 row)
```

You can even simplify the function further with this:

```
postgres=# CREATE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13)) RETURNS BOOLEAN  
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM client WHERE  phone=inPhone) ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# select * from searchUser('foo');
 searchuser 
------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from searchUser('bar');
 searchuser 
------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchUser(inPhone VARCHAR(13)) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM client WHERE phone = inPhone));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kJR21jOR)